# google_maps_flutter - programmatically set rotation to 0 (bearing to north)

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps-flutter, google-maps-flutter-web

When I create the GoogleMap widget I can set:

```
initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: _initialCameraPosition,
                    zoom: 12.0,
                    bearing: 0.0
                  ),
```

but after the user changes the rotation, how can I set the bearing to 0.0 again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `GoogleMap.onMapCreated` callback to store a reference to the `GoogleMapController` parameter it has.

```
GoogleMap(
      onMapCreated: (controller) => /* store the controller in state */,
      ...
    );
```

Then, use it to set the camera position:

```
controller.animateCamera(
      CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
         CameraPosition(
          bearing: /* set your desired bearing */,
          ...
         ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Ah great, I missed the newCameraPosition option in CameraUpdate.